# Adding new column to dataframe of different length from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a new column to my dataframe for each time I run my funciton. This causes the error: 'ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index'. I assume this is because the list I add to df as a new column varies in length with every run of the function.

I have seen many threads suggest using concad, but this probably won't work for me as I can't seem to use concad and just overwrite my existing df - and I need one complete df at the end with a column from each run of my function.

My code functions like this:

```
df = DataFrame()
mylist = []

def myfunc(number):
    mylist = []
    for x in range(0,10):
        if 'some condition':
            mylist.append(x)
    df['results%d' % number] = mylist
```

So for each function iteration I'm adding contents of 'mylist' as a new dataframe column. At second iteration this causes above mentioned error. I need some way of letting python ignore index/column length. From the threads suggesting using concad, I get that passing that giving the instruction 'axis=1' fixes the problem of different lengths - so solution might be parallel to that.

Alternative I could create a range of lists either before function definition or at beginning of it - one list for each 'number' parameter passed to the function, but this is a very primitive solution

Comment: How are the values in `myList` related to the existing rows in `df`?

Comment: Actually I currently have no data/columns in df before running my function - it's just my attempt at a way to save data from multiple calls of the function. Should just be a df containing columns of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do, but maybe you want something like this?

```
df = DataFrame()

def myfunc(number):
    row_index = 0
    for x in range(0,10):
        if 'some condition':
            df.loc[row_index, 'results%d' % number] = x
            row_index += 1
```

Comment: If not sure what your solution does. But you are locating already existing columns which is not relevant (as I read your code). I need to use my df as a place to save information to, which I'm trying to accomplish by creating new columns and filling them from inside the function

Comment: `df.loc[row_index,column_index] = x` will create the row and column if they do not already exist.  This lets you add entries to the DataFrame one value at a time instead of trying to create a column separately and add it all at once.

Comment: Thats surprising to me since on http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html it says: 
'.loc will raise a KeyError when the items are not found.' But i might just be missing something here

Comment: Your solution solves my problem as with that way of doing it I avoid an error caused by the different in data lengths betweens columns - now empty field are NaN as had I done concat between df's. Thanks

Comment: It will raise an error if you are trying to read the value, but will succeed if you are setting the value.